# induction proof of recursive multiplication

Tags: induction

```
mul(a,0) = 0 
mul(a,n) =
    if a%2 then mul(2a,n/2)
    else mul(2a, (n-1)/2)+a


mul(a,n) = a*n
```

Comment: So this defines a function ${\sf mul}\colon \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$ by recursion. What to prove?

Comment: So just do induction on $n$. The base case follows from $a\cdot 0 = 0$. For the step use the recursion. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm clear with possibles bases cases, mul(a,0) = 0, mul(a,1) = mul(2a,0)+a = a, mul(a, 2) = mul(2a,1) = mul(4a,0)+2a = 0+2a... But i don't know that to use for induction step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\mul{{\sf mul}}$We do induction on $n$. For $n = 0$, we have 
$$ \mul(a,0) = 0 = a \cdot 0 $$
for any $a \in \mathbb N$.

Now let $n \ge 1$, suppose $\mul(b,k) = b \cdot k$ holds for any $b \in \mathbb N$ and any $k < n$. Let $a \in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Then if $n$ is even
$$ \mul(a,n) = \mul(2a, n/2) $$
Now as $n/2 < n$, we have by induction hypothesis
$$ \mul(a,n) = \mul(2a, n/2) = 2a \cdot \frac n2  =a  \cdot n. $$
If $n$ is odd, we have again by recursion and induction hypothesis
$$ \mul(a,n) = \mul\left(2a,\frac{n-1}2\right)  + a
   = 2a \cdot \frac{n-1}2 + a = a(n-1) + a = a\cdot n. $$
This proves $\mul(a,n) = an$.

Comment: mul(thanks,inf)!